# CSS3 Transition delay doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Why my transition delay doesn't work? It hovers normally without delay, but I have couple elements and I want them to delay after hover.

```
.line11 .main .box .arrow1 img{
    position: relative;
    left: 150px;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: -19px;
        -webkit-transition-delay: 3s;
        -moz-transition-delay: 3s;
        -o-transition-delay: 3s;
        transition-delay: 3s;
    }

    .line11:hover .main .box .arrow1 img{
    position: relative; 
    left: 150px;
    z-index: 0;
    bottom: -19px;
    height: 13px;
    }
```

Comment: What property/properties are you trying to transition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mwps22kr/)

Some errors in your css:

1. You don't declare any transition:

   ```
   transition: all 0.5s; //for example
   ```
2. You only change height but you don't initalize this property in your css:

   ```
   height: 100px; // height: anything;
   ```